# Cyclical jQuery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I'm using jQuery tabs to create a unique user interface for a project I'm working on, and I'm having some trouble getting them to do what I need them to do.

The layout:
[image: Layout]

The years running along the top would be the tabs.

What I'm trying to do is this: when the user clicks one of the years, 2009 for example, that tab will slide over to become the center tab (along with its content), new tabs for preceding years will be added to the left, and excess tabs will be removed from the right. So in the end there will be the same number of tabs, with the selected year in the center.

I feel like my experience with jQuery is not adequate to accomplish this. How would I accomplish this sort of functionality?

Code so far:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({selected: 3});//just selects the center tab(probably needs to be changed)
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
           select: function(event, ui) {
                    var year = $(".year").val();
                    //figure how many tabs are left and right (year - selected year)
                    //delete and add tabs
                    //change class of selected tab
               }
        });
});
```

I've got a couple notes in there that are kind of an idea of the process as I though it might need to go.

```
<div class='navBar' id='tabs'>
<ul>
    <li class='navElement'><a href="post.php?year=<?php echo($year-3);?>"><?php echo($year-3);?></a></li>
    <li class='navElement'><a href="post.php?year=<?php echo($year-2);?>"><?php echo($year-2);?></a></li>
    <li class='navElement'><a href="post.php?year=<?php echo($year-1);?>"><?php echo($year-1);?></a></li>
    <li class='navFocus'><a href="post.php?year=<?php echo($year);?>"><?php echo($year);?></a></li>
    <li class='navElement'><a href="post.php?year=<?php echo($year+1);?>"><?php echo($year+1);?></a></li>
    <li class='navElement'><a href="post.php?year=<?php echo($year+2);?>"><?php echo($year+2);?></a></li>
    <li class='navElement'><a href="post.php?year=<?php echo($year+3);?>"><?php echo($year+3);?></a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1"></div>
<div id="tabs-2"></div>
<div id="tabs-3"></div>
<div  id="tabs-4"></div>
<div id="tabs-5"></div>
<div id="tabs-6"></div>
<div id="tabs-7"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried so far?

Comment: I'll be honest, I haven't really tried anything yet. I'm not sure how to start. I've just been trying to get autocomplete working for jQuery in eclipse. I'll post how my tabs are set up, though.

Comment: Personally, I think you're better off implementing this yourself. As far as I know, jQuery UI tabs don't cater for things like this easily.

Comment: Oh god. You mean write the whole business myself from scratch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would also skip jQuery UI Tabs. The actual tab functionality is not (by far) the biggest problem here.

This is a start: http://jsfiddle.net/8aGC4/2/ but it'll require some tweaking on your part. Hopefully it can get you started though.

If the code isn't clear enough feel free to ask!

**HTML**

```
<nav class="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#year-2000">2000</a></li><li><a href="#year-2001">2001</a></li><li><a href="#year-2002">2002</a></li><li><a href="#year-2003">2003</a></li><li><a href="#year-2004">2004</a></li><li><a href="#year-2005">2005</a></li><li><a href="#year-2006">2006</a></li><li><a href="#year-2007">2007</a></li><li><a href="#year-2008">2008</a></li><li><a href="#year-2009">2009</a></li><li><a href="#year-2010">2010</a></li><li><a href="#year-2011">2011</a></li><li><a href="#year-2012">2012</a></li><li><a href="#year-2013">2013</a></li><li><a href="#year-2014">2014</a></li><li><a href="#year-2015">2015</a></li><li><a href="#year-2016">2016</a></li><li><a href="#year-2017">2017</a></li><li><a href="#year-2018">2018</a></li><li><a href="#year-2019">2019</a></li><li><a href="#year-2020">2020</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="year-2000">2000 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2001">2001 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2002">2002 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2003">2003 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2004">2004 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2005">2005 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2006">2006 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2007">2007 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2008">2008 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2009">2009 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2010">2010 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2011">2011 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2012">2012 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2013">2013 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2014">2014 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2015">2015 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2016">2016 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2017">2017 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2018">2018 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2019">2019 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
    <div id="year-2020">2020 - Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font: 12px/1.2 Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #666;
}

nav.tabs {
    width: 630px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    nav.tabs ul {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

        nav.tabs ul li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0;
            font-size: 0;
        }

            nav.tabs ul li a {
                background: #f6f6f6;

                display: block;
                width: 58px;
                padding: 5px;

                color: #666;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 12px;

                border-left: 1px solid #fefefe;
                border-right: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
            }

div.tab-content {
    width: 210px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

    div.tab-content div {
        background: #f6f6f6;
        display: none;
        padding: 5px;
    }
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    var tabs = $('nav.tabs a');
    var tabContent = $('div.tab-content > div');

    tabs.click(function () {
        // Hide and deselect previous tab
        tabs.filter('.active').removeClass('active').animate({width: '58px'}, 100);
        tabContent.slideUp(100);

        // Select and show this tab
        var tab = $(this);

        tab.addClass('active').animate({width: '198px'}, 100);
        $(tab.attr('href')).slideDown(100);

        // Scroll tab container so that current tab is centered
        var currentTab = tabs.index(tab);

        // 3 = num tabs to the left of selected tab, 70 = width of tabs
        $('nav.tabs').scrollTo((currentTab - 3) * 70, {axis: 'x', duration: 100});

        return false;
    });

    $('a[href="#year-2014"]').click();
});
```

Comment: Woah. Man, you nailed it. Wicked fast, too.

Comment: I've got it almost working, but for some reason all of the tab elements are displaying all at once. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like you might have used the same IDs for every tab content? Each tab content should have a unique ID and each link should point to each ID for the code to work properly. BTW: Unless you figured it out already you can use `animate('width', '50px/90px')` instead of `add/removeClass('active')` to actually get a bit of slide and you could use the `scrollTo()`-plugin instead of `.scrollLeft` to animate the scrolling as well.

Comment: Do you mean each div inside the tab-content div? I copied and pasted them from your code, and they all look different to me. And thank you for pointing out the animation thing! I was actually planning on something like that.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. It was my fault. I had a float on one of the elements.

Comment: Here's a version with animations and some less screamy colours: http://jsfiddle.net/8aGC4/2/